# VSCode using Remote SSH - Run Tasks on Host Machine

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-tasks

I am connected to a remote server via SSH using the `Remote - SSH` plugin by VSCode. I would like to run a task with the path to the remote file on the local machine.

Specifically, I have a HTML file on the remote machine that I would like to preview/interact with on my local windows machine using an URL.

My task.json should look something like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Open Remote HTML",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "start https://url_to_remote.com/${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: Additionally, I have tasks that should continue run on the remote machine and I would like the option to run on the local or host machine on a per task basis.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to set up a task in VSCode to run a command on your local machine that'll open the browser and access the file on your remote machine? If so, one way to do this without tasks: set up a static web server on the remote machine, and just alt-tab to firefox and hit F5 on the loaded page. Another way would be to set up a task on the remote machine to upload the file to your computer, then repeat the first steps. If you require local code execution, set up something simple like Autohotkey to open the browser to the remote URL, rather than using tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! I would like to clarify that my remote machine produces several html report files, which are not modified, and I can view any of the reports in the host machine at a URL like: `https://url_to_remote.com/path/to/index.html`. I would like to automate the process of needing to copy the base URL, copying the file path in VSCode and searching the address. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately running a task locally while using the Remote SSH extension is not possible, though it looks like there's sufficient demand and it has been added to their backlog:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/168

If you're determined to have this, though, a very hacky way to go about this would be to:

1. Set up a basic webserver on your local machine at localhostIP
2. Expose an endpoint that reads a URL parameter named file (http://localhostIP:3000/?file=blah.html) and opens a new tab in firefox/your browser of choice like so:

   ```
   firefox --new-tab https://remotehostIP:3000/blah.html
   ```

   Here's a one line web server runnable from bash through a local terminal (ctrl+shift+P, search integrated to start a local terminal while connected to remote host). This web server accomplishes steps 1 and 2 mentioned here (ctrl+c to stop web server):

   ```
   echo "const http = require('http');const {exec} = require('child_process');http.createServer(function (req, res) {h='http://remotehostIP:3000/';exec(\`firefox --new-tab \${h+req.url.slice('/?file='.length)}\`);res.end();}).listen(3000);" | node
   ```

   Indented, easier to read code:

   ```
   const http = require('http');
   const {exec} = require('child_process');

   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
       h="http://remotehostIP:3000/";
       exec(`firefox --new-tab ${h+req.url.slice("/?file=".length)}`);
       res.end();
   }).listen(3000);
   ```
3. Lastly, create a task that curls and hits that localhostIP webserver and passes along `${relativeFile}`. This task runs on the remote machine, but will trigger your localhostIP's webserver to open firefox. Here's what that might look like

   ```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "show current html file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "curl",
            "args": ["http://localhostIP:3000/?file=${relativeFile}"],           
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
   ```

I think for now this is about as good as you're going to get with a best-effort solution while not investing a bunch of time. Let me know if you run into any issues!